# Debugging a maven Application inside Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, eclipse-plugin

Is there any difference between these two approaches while debugging the Application 
 When we put debug points and  deploy  using Eclipse  maven Plugin 
and by this approach 
creating a server instance in the Eclipse IDE ( starting it in the debug mode) and  putting the debug points under eclipse and deploying it as a war into server

Please guide me thank you very much .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in both ways ...rather creating a server instance in eclipse i prefer to create  server externally and deploy your war file and do remote debugging..

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is time: Creating a WAR, deploying it and (re)starting the external server costs time.

In my projects, I have a Java class which creates a Jetty server instance and which uses the classpath provided by Eclipse to locate all resources (plus some custom setup for reloading).

In my case, creating the WAR takes 10 minutes (compiling everything, running all the tests, creating a 75MB WAR). If I skip the tests, it takes 2 minutes. Starting Tomcat takes 35 seconds. Deploying takes another 7 seconds. Starting the app in Tomcat takes 135 seconds. So that's at least 297 seconds or about 5 minutes.

With my hand-optimized Jetty setup, it takes 45 seconds.

If I change a class file, I have to create a new WAR, etc. In Jetty, I make a change, save and the Jetty instance restarts in 7 seconds.

So the difference is being able to make 12 (Tomcat+WAR) or 514 changes per hour.